# Why is there a value constructor in addition to the type constructor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-constructor

I'm a newcomer to Haskell and am currently going through Real World Haskell. The book says the type constructor is used only in the type signature while the value constructor is used in actual code. It also gives an example of a declaration to show that the names for both are independent of each other. Why are two constructors needed in the first place, if only one of them is used in actual code? Since we would not use the type constructor in actual code, what purpose does the type constructor serve?

Comment: The phrase "actual code" is unfortunate, because it implies that you wouldn't use the type constructor in programs, when the authors actually meant that type constructors are only used for type annotations.  This is equivalent to saying that you don't need the keywords "int" or "long" in C because you don't use them in actual code (they're only used in declarations, which don't count as "actual code" by this standard).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe the names are a little bit misleading. A **type constructor** represents the name of the type you're declaring. They're called like that because they build types, not values: indeed, being (possibly) parameterized on type variables they define a family of types. They act something like C++'s templates and Java's generics. In `data MyType a b = Constr a b`, MyType is a type constructor that takes two types `a` and `b` to build a new type `(MyType a b)`.

A **value constructor** is the only part you would call a "constructor" in other (object oriented) languages, because you need it in order to build values for that type. So, in the previous example, if you take the value constructor `Constr :: a -> b -> MyType a b`, you may build a value `Constr "abc" 'd' :: MyType [Char] Char`.

Comment: May I ask how to improve my answer to get rid of that -1? What's wrong?

Answer (score 18):

It's a bit like saying "why do we need classes *and* objects if objects are the only thing that actually runs?"

The two sorts of constructors do different jobs. Type constructors go in type signatures. Value constructors go in runnable code.

In the simplest case, a type "constructor" *is* just a type name. In the simplest case, a type has only one value constructor. So you end up with things like

`data Point = Point Int Int`

You might say to yourself "now why the heck to I need to write `Point` twice?"

But now consider a less trivial example:

`data Tree x = Leaf x | Branch (Tree x) (Tree x)`

Here `Tree` is a type constructor. You give it a type argument, and it "constructs" a type. So `Tree Int` is one type, `Tree String` is another type, and so on. (Like templates in C++, or generics in Java or Eiffel.)

On the other hand, `Leaf` is a value constructor. Given a value, it makes a 1-node tree out of it. So `Leaf 5` is a `Tree Int` value, `Leaf "banana"` is a `Tree String` value, and so on.

Similarly for `Branch`. It takes two tree values and constructs a tree node with those trees as children. For example, `Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 7)` is a `Tree Int` value.

Answer (score 7):

One convenient way to get the intuition about Types and Values is that the former are **compile-time** values while the latter are **run-time** values. In other words, Type constructors are constructors of values in the set of Haskell Types, for the sole aim of typing your program at compile time. That also means you can not construct a type at run-time, and you can not construct a value at compile-time.

So, because you can not explicitly branch at run-time on the basis of a type value (though you can implicitly with typeclasses), Type constructors are totally useless as run-time objects and in many cases are totally absent in the final binary. Conversely, because values constructors allows to construct values in the set of their type at run-time, they are totally useless as compile-time object.

Because of this simple property, Type constructors and Value constructors can share names unambiguously.

Comment: This is the answer simplest to understand for people coming from an imperative background!