# Haskell: Multiple declaration of datatype

Tags: haskell

I have a little problem while creating data types.

I have two data types, Football and Tennis

```
data Football a  = Football
  { players       :: Players a    
  , Stadium       :: Stadium  a
  }     

data Tennis a  = Tennis
  { players1      :: Players a    
  , Stadium1      :: Stadium  a
  }
```

And I want to create an other datatype Sport using as a constructor the datatype football and tennis
`data Sport a =  Football a  | Tennis a`
and I get the following error, multiple declarations of Football I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Best regards

Comment: Well you made a constructor `Football :: Players a -> Stadium a -> Football a`, and now you made an additional constructor `Football :: Sport`.

Comment: Also note that record field names must be lowercase: `Stadium` can't be a field.

Comment: I correct my mistake by adding Sport a  = Football a | Tennis a but still the problem continues

Comment: Other potential duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551751/625403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10242709/625403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12543662/625403

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your idea is correct in spirit but Haskell uses tagged unions (also called "discriminated unions", "disjoint unions",  "variants", and "sum types"). This means you need an additional tag to determine if Sport is constructed with Football or if it is constructed with Tennis.

```
data Sport = SportFootball Football | SportTennis Tennis
```

These tags are known in Haskell as *data constructors*. That is, this defines a constructor `SportFootball :: Football -> Sport` and a constructor `SportTennis :: Tennis -> Sport`.

Suppose Haskell did not require this extra tag, then what would be this type?

```
data UntaggedInt = Int | Int
```

An untagged union should have the property `(x | x) = x` and so this must be equivalent to:

```
data UntaggedInt = Int
```

Whereas with tagged unions we can define:

```
data TaggedInt = This Int | That Int
```

That is, tagged unions are not *idempotent*.

Also consider something else which happens without constructors. Suppose we have a definition such as:

```
data UntaggedLists = String | [String]
```

And now we are tasked with finding the type of the expression `"hello world"`. Should the type be `String` or `UntaggedLists`? Then suppose we have another similar definition:

```
data AnotherUntaggedLists = String | [String]
```

Is it true that `UntaggedLists` and `AnotherUntaggedLists` are equal types?

These are not unanswerable questions, but it does demonstrate a profound systematic difference between having tags and not.

Comment: Thank you my friend! Beautiful answer :)